# Using Catch-A-Ride customization item doesn't unlock the vehicle skin?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm having a problem with unlocking the Catch-A-Ride skins. Iv'e found a decent amount of Catch-A-Ride customization items and used them from my inventory. However when I get to CAR Station I can't pick any skins I unlocked (they don't appear in the list).

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the right car? Skins only apply to one vehicle I think

Comment: @BenBrocka What do you mean the right car?When i went to my inventory and used CAR (Catch-A-Ride) customization item it told me i unlocked it in CAR Station.I can only pick one type of vehicle atm and the only thing i can change about it is the weapon it uses and default skins (unlocked skins wont show on the list.

Comment: There's more than one vehicle, it might have been for the Bandit Technical for example. Skins tell you which vehicle they're for before you use them, but I don't know of any way to check which you have if you don't have the vehicle

Comment: @BenBrocka How do you unlock/get new vehicles (don't want to ask a new question about it)?

Comment: Pretty sure they're all unlocked by the story. You'll get the first one around level 10-12 I think

Comment: @Ben You should put that as the answer to this question. I was confused when this happened to me and I could see other people asking this later on, as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you got a skin for a vehicle you don't have unlocked yet. There's multiple types of vehicles in Borderlands 2 (not just Machine Gun vs Rocket Launcher), and skins only work for one vehicle.

You can check the vehicle your skin is for before you use it, but once you use it you'll only see it when you see the skin in the menu. Skins are unlocked regardless of whether you're using the class/unlocked the vehicle in question, and they're unlocked for all of your characters.

Keep playing and you'll get the vehicle the skin matches. The skin should show up with "NEW" next to it when you unlock the right vehicle.